# Unable to Resolve Machine Names via Domain Controller

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, internal-dns, amazon-vpc, vpc-peering

I have two Amazon AWS VPC's connected via a peering connection, where I have enabled DNS resolution between them like so:

[image]

I am also using an internal domain controller to provide DNS using the AWS DHCP Options Sets (I have also tried using Amazon Provided DNS in one of my VPC's).

In one of my Ubuntu EC2 instances when I perform an `nslookup MACHINE-NAME` to a Windows EC2 instance in the other VPC, it fails to resolve. I can however, use the internal IP of the Windows instance to talk to it.

What could be stopping machine name DNS resolution from working?

Comment: Do you have a VPN or Direct Connect between your On prime AD server and the VPC's? Can you resolve addresses of machines inside a vpc?

Comment: Also this might help. https://serverfault.com/questions/834769/aws-dns-resolution-only-resolves-internal-ip-one-way?rq=1